# R and ggplot2 - how to dynamically hide axis variable labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple box chart and i would like to dynamically hide the variable labels so that only 1 of them is printed at a time:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

mtcars <- as.data.frame(mtcars)
mtcars$CarName <- rownames(mtcars)
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

#Only want to label 6 clyinder boxplot
mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(Label = ifelse(cyl == 6, 
                        "6 Cylinders", NA))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(y=mpg, x = cyl)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

What I am trying to achieve is to still draw 3 box plots (1 for cylinder 4, 6 and 8) but I only want to display the label for cylinder 6.

In my dataset, the column 'Label' is populated with the cylinder that I *want* to label, and has a null value for the ones I do not want to label. This column updates dynamically so I need to be able to use that in order to label the correct box plot.

Below is my box plot so far. I want to label 6:

[image: Box Plot so far - want to add 6]

Bonus Question: Would be good if i can also fill the colour/ bolder lines for the 6 cylinder box so it looks different from the rest.

Comment: Bonus Question: Would be good if i can also fill the colour/ bolder lines for the 6 cylinder box so it looks different from the rest.

Comment: Please **edit your question** with any additional information / request you may have. Information in comments is easy to miss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create labels with `geom_text` or `geom_label`. In this kind of boxplot it is useful to set the `y` placement for the label manually as I have, or bind it to another variable. I have alse created a simple variable to emphasize the color for the value of 6 cylinders.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

mtcars <- as.data.frame(mtcars)
mtcars$CarName <- rownames(mtcars)
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(Label = ifelse(cyl == 6, 
                        "6 Cylinders", NA),
         fill_color = cyl == 6) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y=mpg, x = cyl)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = fill_color)) + geom_label(aes(label = Label, y = 10)) +
  guides(fill = F)
```

Comment: Thanks, how do i go about systematically determining what the Y value is? In this scenario you've hard-coded y = 10, but what if it was 4 Cylinders or 8 Cylinders? My actual data has 17 box plots, and depending on who logs into the system to view, the y value will need to change.

Comment: @Oneiricer you could assign it to anything for example y = mean(mpg) or mean(mpg) / 2 or whatever works for your purpose:) if my answer above was what you were looking for, could you click accept answer?